# Extract text from pdf horizontally in Python

Tags: python, text-extraction, pypdf, pdfminer

I want to extract text from pdf's horizontally. Pdfminer is presently doing it vertically. How can I do it using pdfminer or pypdf2 or anything else in python keeping the format of extracted text, same as the pdf